# Enterprise Architect Rule Task: Rule Composer Validation warns "Same action logic is bound to different rules"

Tags: enterprise-architect, business-rules

I am using EA 14.0.1422 and I am having trouble getting Business Rules to work or to understand them how they are supposed to work.

I have 2 business rules and a rule task as seen in the following image:

[image: Business Rules and Rule Task with supporting Class and Enumeration]

Now when I start the "Rule Composer" and bind the rules to the decision table and assign values my table looks like this:

[image: Rule Composer IsValidBorn]

For `Person.Birthday` I have defined the following "allowable values":
[image: Person.Birthday Allowable Values]

However, when I start validation I get the following warning (and error):

```
Warning: Same action logic is bound to different rules! 
Error: Conflicting rule as different condition logics found for same rule!  
Validation complete - 1 error(s), 1 warning(s)
```

When I click on the warning the following parts are being highlighted:

[image: Rule Composer Validation Warning]

When I click on the error the following parts are being highlighted:

[image: Rule Composer Validation Error]

This is how I defined the supporting classes:

[image: Supporting Classes Birthday and System.DateTime]

My questions if anyone could give me a hint:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How is this supposed to work?

Thank you very much for your help!